# RTSP server stream camera

Tags: mfc, live555

I'm working with RTSP server and camera user MFC, I must stream camera and the client will use VLC to watch camera in real time.

I'm a beginner user of live555. I tried demo live555 code, and I was able to stream a file from my computer, but I don't know how to stream my camera.

I spent 1 week reading documents and searching on google. I know that I should write a frame source for the camera sub classing live555, encode the frames, and next use live555 to stream it.
But I don't know how do write a frame source camera.

Any document, example link etc.. you can  give me.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look on my experience based on live555 that implement a FramedSource reading a  H264 stream from V4L2 https://github.com/mpromonet/v4l2rtspserver

The implementation of the FramedSource is in :

- https://github.com/mpromonet/v4l2rtspserver/blob/master/inc/DeviceSource.h
- https://github.com/mpromonet/v4l2rtspserver/blob/master/src/DeviceSource.cpp